# How to Style Divs which are not material components angular2 material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using angular2 material in my application. I wish to style my app in material theme. Places where i'm using material components directly(like md-button, md-card), everything is fine. But I'm not sure how to style regular divs using the same theme. I don't want to import any other materialize css. So far, I could find only one class(mat-elevation-z*) which i can use to elevate divs. But i'm not able what all classes are available for me to use.

Comment: @isherwood, I totally understand your concern here. I've put it in a slightly better way.  Please let me know if it's still a bad question.

Comment: That's a good question, and it's actually quite challenging. AM sort of assumes that any element you wish to follow the theme will be one of their components (as @joshsisley hinted). Your overall theme should be mostly static and simple. You can't apply theme with simple classes because of all the behind-the-scenes directives involved with actual components.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the different components that can be used: [material 2 component docs](https://github.com/angular/material2/wiki/Design-doc-directory) and this is a link to the Github: [github/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2)

Hope this helps!